# Safari's Voiceover only reads webpage title and summary, how to make it read the entire page upon on load?

Tags: accessibility

Macbook's voiceover is only reading the webpage title and page summary on Safari and stops. It's not reading the entire page from title to the end of the page. It works on Chrome, it reads the entire page automatically without key press. I still need to press Control + Option + A to continue it reading. Is this normal in Safari?

after reading the page title and summary it will say

You are currently in a link...

And I will press Control + Option + A to continue reading the remaining elements in the page.